# Using Word Break on a specific word using CSS

Tags: css, paragraph, word-break

I'm trying to break a specific word using css.

The word is "sales/telemarketing", and I'm trying to break the word after the "/tele" part. I'm trying to avoid using `<br>` as it might affect the way the layout for the paragraph tag.

Is there a way to break it using CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you said you want to avoid `<br>`, but there is `<wbr>`..

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/U5CwU/3/)

Example usage:

```
<p>some random text and stuff sales/tele<wbr>marketing some more words here</p>
```

If you re-size the `p`, the word will break after *tele*.

[**See MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr)

Sadly, there is limited support for `<wbr>`, as it isn't supported by IE10.

---

I just thought of a random CSS alternative..

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/U5CwU/4/)

**HTML**

```
<p>some random text and stuff sales/<span>tele</span> marketing some more words here</p>
```

**CSS**

```
span {
    margin-right:-4px;
}
```

Basically, you just include a space after *tele*, therefore it breaks to a new line.. By selecting the word *tele*, you can remove the space.. not ideal - but it works nonetheless.

Comment: Tried `<wbr>` but after taking a look about it I used an alternative `&#8203;` instead.

Comment: `<wbr>` is widely supported, especially if you add `wbr:after { content: "\200B"; }` into your stylesheet. But it is a wrong tool for specifying that a *word* may be divided into two lines, since it breaks without adding a hyphen. And the use of `&#8203;` (which is really the character-level counterpart) has the same problem.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I was waiting for you to post something negative about this - thanks for yet another downvote :)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela You are completely **WRONG** in stating that `wbr` is widely supported - It doesn't even work in IE10 !!

Comment: I downvoted simply because the answer is provably wrong and does not even address the question asked (how to divide *after* the “/tele” part). Regarding IE 10, just try it with the CSS addition I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify a word division point in CSS (except in a contrived way, which would be just an unreliable emulation of the proper way). Instead, include a hyphenation hint, the soft hyphen, U+00AD, either by entering it directly if you know how to, or using the reference `&shy;`:

```
sales/tele&shy;marketing
```

You can add other hyphenation hints to the same word if you like. And you can add `<wbr>` after `/` to specify an allowed direct break point (no hyphen appears if the string is divided).